# Can the exhaust of a range hood be insulated between the 6in duct and the chimney casing?

Tags: hvac, range-hood

I am installing a range hood and I would like to reduce suction and vibration noise as much as possible.

Is it possible to insulate the empty compartment between the 6in exhaust duct pipe and the casing of the range hood chimney to provide sound insulation? if yes, what type of material is best to provide insulation?

Comment: I would think a sound reduction material like rockwool would work fine.